# Buscar caracteres consecutivos en una cadena PHP

Tags: php

Hola quiero buscar dentro de una cadena de texto, caracteres consecutivos como ser:

```
qwerty, ertyu, tyuiop

asdfgh, dfghjk, fghjkl

zxcvbn, xcvbnm
```

*minuscuslas* o *mayusculas* indistintamente.

Gracias.

Comment: por favor, puedes explicar con ejemplo que es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado/intentado para resolver el problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hice este código que espero pueda ayudarte. Agregué una variable, tolerancia, que es la que va a indicar la cantidad seguidas de letras vas a detectar como una repetición.
Funciona incluso de forma invertida, aunque si no lo quieres de esa forma, solo quita el abs() de la primera función.

```
<?php
function verificar_consecutivos($cadena, $tolerancia) {
    $keyb_map = '1234567890|qwertyuiop|asdfghjklñ|zxcvbnm,.-';
    $longitud_cadena = strlen($cadena);
    if($longitud_cadena < $tolerancia) {
        // Si long de la cadena es menor que la cant de caracteres repetidos a buscar
        return FALSE;
    }
    for($i=0; $i<=($longitud_cadena-$tolerancia); $i++) {
        $consecutivos = TRUE;
        for($j=0; $j<($tolerancia-1); $j++) {
            $pos_carac_actual_keyb = strpos($keyb_map, $cadena[$i+$j]);
            $pos_carac_siguiente_keyb = strpos($keyb_map, $cadena[$i+$j+1]);
            $diferencia_consecutivos = abs($pos_carac_siguiente_keyb - $pos_carac_actual_keyb);
            if($diferencia_consecutivos !== 1) {
                // Si no son caracteres consecuntivos se especifica y se termina el for.
                $consecutivos = FALSE;
                $j = $tolerancia; // Terminar el for $j anticipadamente
            }
        }
        if($consecutivos === TRUE) {
            // Apenas encuentra un consecutivo, ya no vale la pena seguir buscando mas.
            $i = $longitud_cadena; // Termina el for $i
        }
    }
    return $consecutivos;
}

function caracteres_consecutivos($cadena, $tolerancia) {
    if(verificar_consecutivos(strtolower($cadena), $tolerancia)) {
        echo 'Hay caracteres consecutivos de teclado'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'No hay caracteres consecutivos'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}


caracteres_consecutivos('yasdfgkytrb', 5); // Consecutivos 'asdfg'
caracteres_consecutivos('yaddfggytrb', 4); // No hay 4 consecutivos
caracteres_consecutivos('qwe', 3); // Consecutivos 'qwe'
caracteres_consecutivos('qwe', 6); // No hay 6 consecutivos
caracteres_consecutivos('', 5); // No hay 5 consecutivos
caracteres_consecutivos('lksdrtyu', 4); // Consecutivos 'rtyu'
caracteres_consecutivos('lksduytr', 4); // Consecutivos 'rtyu' (a la inversa)
```

Y la salida es:

```
Hay caracteres consecutivos de teclado
No hay caracteres consecutivos
Hay caracteres consecutivos de teclado
No hay caracteres consecutivos
No hay caracteres consecutivos
Hay caracteres consecutivos de teclado
Hay caracteres consecutivos de teclado
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizá este código puede ayudarte:

```
<?php
$text1 = "qwerty";
$text2 = "asdfgh";
$text3 = "zxcvbn";

$diccionario_qwerty = [0=>'q', 1=>'w', 2=>'e', 3=>'r', 4=>'t', 5=>'y', 6=>'u', 7=>'i', 8=>'o', 9=>'p',
10=>'a', 11=>'s', 12=>'d', 13=>'f', 14=>'g', 15=>'h', 16=>'j', 17=>'k',
18=>'z', 19=>'x', 20=>'c', 21=>'v', 22=>'b', 23=>'n', 24=>'m', 25=>'q', 26=>''];

$_text1 = str_split($text1);
foreach ($_text1 as &$c) 
    $c = $diccionario_qwerty[array_search($c, $diccionario_qwerty)+1];

$text1 = implode($_text1);

print_r($text1);
?>
```

No esta en una función ya que no se comportamiento tendría exactamente.

Answer (score 0):

Un buen principio podria ser asi:

```
<?php

$cadena = "biologia"; //aqui hay 2 caracteres consecutivos 'io'

$linea1 = 'qwertyuiop';
$linea2 = 'asdfghjkl';
$linea3 = 'zxcvbnm';
$lineas = [$linea1,$linea2,$linea3];

$longitud = mb_strlen($cadena);


for ($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++) {
    for($j=2; $j<=$longitud-$i; $j++){
        $extrae = substr($cadena,$i,$j);
        foreach ($lineas as $clave => $valor) {
        if(preg_match('/'.$extrae.'/i',$valor) == 1){
            print_r('En la cadena '.$cadena.' hay un bloque de caracteres consecutivos en teclado que son: '.$extrae);
            echo "<br>";    
        }  //end if
        } //end foreach
    } //end for with $j
} //end for with $i
```

La salida para este cadena en particular seria:

```
En la cadena biologia hay un bloque de caracteres consecutivos en teclado que son: io
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text1 = "qwerty";
$text2 = "asdfgh";
$text3 = "zxcvbn";

$diccionario_qwerty = [0=>'q', 1=>'w', 2=>'e', 3=>'r', 4=>'t', 5=>'y', 6=>'u', 7=>'i', 8=>'o', 9=>'p',
10=>'a', 11=>'s', 12=>'d', 13=>'f', 14=>'g', 15=>'h', 16=>'j', 17=>'k',
18=>'z', 19=>'x', 20=>'c', 21=>'v', 22=>'b', 23=>'n', 24=>'m', 25=>'q', 26=>''];

$_text1 = str_split($text1);
foreach ($_text1 as &$c) 
    $c = $diccionario_qwerty[array_search($c, $diccionario_qwerty)+1];

$text1 = implode($_text1);

print_r($text1);
?>
```